# mkusb: No target device or bad target device

Tags: command-line, live-usb, mkusb

I am trying to run `mkusb` to create USB device to have Live Ubuntu with Persistent Storage on it and I am getting `No target device or bad target device`.

Here is the transcript of the session:

```
mkusb
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Usage: mkusb [input-file]      # optional parameter
---------------------------------------------------------------------
d:  dus , guidus, mkusb-dus    - New, easy to use
e: Eleven, sudo -H mkusb-11    - Classic user interface
n: NoX,    sudo mkusb-nox      - original text mode
b: Bas,    sudo mkusb-bas      - basic text mode for old/basic linux
q: Quit
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Select version of mkusb (d/e/n/b/q) d
 dus 12.3.7 
live system or temporary superuser permissions
source device: /dev/sdb4 'live system or temporary superuser permissions'
Drive that contains source file: /dev/sdb
Live drive, that is booted from: /dev/sdb
cands=2

931.5G

931.5G
built-in device
sde
SanDisk_Cruzer_Glide
14.6G
usb
USB or memory card
p_target: target=/dev/14.6G
No target device or bad target device
p_clean:
live system or temporary superuser permissions
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Additional information:**

- Running

`sudo lsblk -o model,name,size,fstype,model,mountpoint /dev/sdb`

outputs:

```
MODEL            NAME    SIZE FSTYPE  MODEL            MOUNTPOINT
Ultra Fit        sdb    57.3G         Ultra Fit        
                 ├─sdb1 13.2G ntfs                     /media/ubuntu/usbdata1
                 ├─sdb2    1M                          
                 ├─sdb3  244M vfat                     
                 ├─sdb4    2G iso9660                  /cdrom
                 └─sdb5 41.9G ext4                     /media/ubuntu/casper-rw
```

- Running

`df -h`

outputs:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.8G     0  2.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           576M  1.7M  575M   1% /run
/dev/sdb4       2.0G  2.0G     0 100% /cdrom
/dev/loop0      1.9G  1.9G     0 100% /rofs
/cow             42G   13G   27G  32% /
tmpfs           2.9G  135M  2.7G   5% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /tmp
/dev/loop1       89M   89M     0 100% /snap/core/7396
/dev/loop2       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1144
/dev/loop3       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/7917
/dev/loop4      128K  128K     0 100% /snap/hello-world/29
/dev/loop5       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1192
/dev/loop6       43M   43M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1313
/dev/loop7       45M   45M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1353
tmpfs           576M   28K  576M   1% /run/user/999
/dev/sdb5        42G   13G   27G  32% /media/ubuntu/casper-rw
/dev/sdb1        14G  2.6G   11G  20% /media/ubuntu/usbdata1
/dev/sde4       2.0G  2.0G     0 100% /media/ubuntu/Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS amd64
/dev/sde5       6.1G  1.1G  4.8G  19% /media/ubuntu/casper-rw1
/dev/sde1       6.2G   33M  6.2G   1% /media/ubuntu/usbdata2
```

Comment: Please run `sudo lsblk -o model,name,size,fstype,model,mountpoint /dev/sda` and `df -h` and edit your original question to show the results of those commands. It will help me analyze the problem.

Comment: @sudodus: Interesting, I launched GParted and that fixed the problem (I got pass the step that was showing the error message).

Comment: Am i understanding correctly, that mkusb works now, after you launched `gparted`? That is interesting. I wonder why. What did you do with the partition table or file system? Or did you do nothing, only looked at it? In that case there might be something with the operating system or USB system or hardware, that did not 'wake up correctly' until you launched `gparted`.

Comment: @sudodus: I didn't do anything with `gparted`, just looked at the partitions. It's possible that something was causing some part of the target device to hibernate. One indication is how the target device is referred to: `p_target: target=/dev/14.6G`. Instead of partition name it shows the size of the USB stick.

Comment: A bug in mkusb might be involved in this problem (a bug that does not occur with my USB pendrives). If you want to, we can do some debugging next week. I have a couple of ideas what to modify and test in mkusb, when your USB pendrives are connected.

Answer (score 0):

you need to edit the file

```
gedit /usr/bin/dus
```

and find the function  **p_list_drives**

I have the line 1168

This function uses the command

```
ls -l /dev/drive/by-id
```

what looks like this

```
root  9 02-06 14:24 usb-Samsung_Flash_01856-0:0 -> ../../sdb
root 10 02-06 14:24 usb-Samsung_Flash_01856-0:0-part1 -> ../../sdb1
```

**p_list_drives** converts any space to a tab
but doesn't do it with double space see

```
root  9 -double space-
root 10
```

we have to add a command to do this otherwise it will be a bad cut

```
p_target: target=/dev/14.6G -bad cut-
```

I changed it so I analyzed only this fragment
losing to keep the idea of the author
and one test works on Debian 11.

Here are the changes I made

line 1681-1682

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-id |grep $i$ |grep -m1 'nvme-[A-Z]' |tr -s ' ' '\t' | tr -s '  ' '\t'  \
   |cut -f8,10|sed -e 's#../../##' |tr '\n' '\t'
```

line 1684-1685

```
ls -l  /dev/disk/by-id |grep -v ^wwn|grep -m1 $i$     |tr -s ' ' '\t' | tr -s '  ' '\t'  \
   |cut -f8,10|sed -e 's#../../##' |tr '\n' '\t'
```

can be uncommented
lini 1689-1690

```
echo "byid:"
cat "$byid"
```

I'm fine now

```
wipe the first Mibibyte
Live drive, that is booted from: /dev/nvme0n1
byid:
ata-HGST_HTS721010A9E630_JR100X4M0NM5HE sda 931,5G
usb-Samsung_Flash_Drive_FIT_0306818100001856-0:0    sdb 59,8G
nvme-Samsung_SSD_960_EVO_250GB_S3ESNX0JB43605R  nvme0n1 232,9G
cands=2
sda
HGST_HTS721010A9E630
931,5G
ata
built-in device
sdb
Samsung_Flash_Drive_FIT
59,8G
usb
USB or memory card
p_target: target=/dev/sdb
```